# my python async script does not process requests quickly?

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I have developed a Python script that allows (in theory) to convert WAV files to MP3 files. I'm trying to make it ASYNC (asyncio) to convert multiple files simultaneously and reduce the processing time.

but that I converted 1 or 10 the time spent and the same. I'm not very good at using async yet

```
class SoundsProcessing:

  

    async def cconvert(self, sem, audioFileIndex, audioFile, aOutputFormat = 'mp3'):
        try:
            async with sem:

                inputfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
                inputfile.write(audioFile)
                outputfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()


                AudioSegment.from_wav(inputfile.name).export(outputfile.name+'.'+aOutputFormat, format=aOutputFormat)

                inputfile.close()

                audio = await readAsyncFile(outputfile.name+'.'+aOutputFormat)

                self.audioFiles[audioFileIndex] = audio

                outputfile.close()

                logger.add('INFO', "Audio Files conversion: " + outputfile.name + " indexed " + str(audioFileIndex) + " is Done")

                return audio

        except Exception as e:
            logger.add('WARNING', "Audio Files conversion: " + str(e))
            return False

    async def audioConversion(self, aOutputAudioFormat = 'mp3'):

        tasks = []
        sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)
        start_at = time.time()

        logger.add('INFO', "Audio Files conversion: Start session for " + str(len(self.audioFiles)) + " files/treatment")

        audioFileIndex = 0
        for audioFile in self.audioFiles:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.cconvert(sem, audioFileIndex, audioFile, aOutputAudioFormat))
            tasks.append(task)
            audioFileIndex = audioFileIndex + 1

        responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await responses

        time_lapse = round(time.time() - start_at, 2)
        query_by_seconds = round(len(self.audioFiles) / time_lapse, 2)
        logger.add('INFO', "Audio Files conversion: End session on " + str(time_lapse) + " seconds ("+str(query_by_seconds)+"q/s)")


    def convert(self, aOutputAudioFormat = 'mp3'):
        self.results = {}

        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        future = asyncio.ensure_future(self.audioConversion(aOutputAudioFormat))
        loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can rewrite the code correctly as "async" - and at first glance it is ok -  but it won't be any faster: this is a CPU bound task - that is, the process takes time in the `.from_wav` call. The asyncio loop will be blocked while that does not return.

What you can try, if you have a multi-core machine is to write the body of your `cconvert` method, the part inside the `with sem:`  block in a synchronous method (forget the async file access), and run that in a ProcessPollExecutor, using the `loop.run_in_executor` call, passing in an explicit `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` instance.